# What does gradient, divergence and curl being independent of co-ordinates means?

Tags: vector-analysis

I am learning vector calculus form Advanced Engineering Mathematics (By Erwin Kreyzeg) and I often see statements like this :-

(1) is $\operatorname{div}(V)$, where $V = [V_1, V_2, V_3]$

> Invariance of the Divergence -
>
> The divergence $\operatorname{div}(V)$ is a scalar function, that is, its values depend only on the points in space (and, of course, on $V$) but not on the choice of the coordinates in (1), so that with respect to other Cartesian coordinates $(x^*, y^*, z^*)$ and corresponding components $V^* = [V_1^*, V_2^*, V_3^*]$ of $V$, then $\operatorname{div}(V) = \nabla^* \cdot V^*$.

What i would like to know it that what does the author means by independent of choice of co-ordinates?
can someone explain it with an example?

Similar things were said for gradient too, but that time i just ignored it cuz it was difficult to comprehend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the author means is that if you have two systems of coordinates $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $(x'_1,x'_2,x'_3)$ respectively for the same domain of space, then the divergence of the field $V$ as represented in space $x_1x_2x_3$ is not different from the divergence of the same field, but represented as $V^*=V'$ in space $x'_1x'_2x'_3.$

The claim, written out explicitly, is that $$\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial V_i}{\partial x_i}=\sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{\partial V'_j}{\partial x'_j}.$$

Although this is beside the point here, an intuitive reason for this is that a scalar field over a region of physical space does not depend on how we *look at* (coordinatize) the space. So obviously its divergence also should be objective -- independent of our frame of reference or point of view.

Comment: So how do we get two different systems? By changing our origin? Say instead of 0,0,0 i take it to be 1,2,5 so for the same point, i'll have different co-ordinates.

Comment: @HentaiOusama That's one possibility, but the relationship between the systems doesn't really matter. An example is the usual rectangular system, and a cylindrical system of coordinates.